# How do I add both a variable and a string into the same print statement?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a basic Python RPG for my friend, and I'm trying to make a stat generator. From what I learned in classes, I'm supposed to `print('Your ability score in this is ' + var1 + '.')`

Here's the entire code block where I'm getting the error.

```
Your elemental attack is '''+ elematk + '''.''')
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
  File "/Users/data censored/Desktop/Basic RPG.py", line 24, in <module>
    Your elemental attack is '''+ elematk + '''.''')
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Maybe I'm just bad at this. I looked at another answer saying that commas separate a string and a var, but that didn't work either.

Comment: `Your elemental attack is '''+ elematk + '''.''')` is not a valid code block in Python.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to put a print tag there first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `elematk` variable is an integer, hence you can't concatenate it with a string.
You can case it to a string type by doing `str(elematk)`

Try doing something like:

```
print('elemental attack is '''+ str(elematk)+ '''.''')
```